# pKa values and basicity

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amines

In considering basicity (particularly of amines), often I find included with the compound a pKa. I understand that the higher the pKa of the conjugate acid, the stronger the base. But when the pKa is listed below a table of bases (for instance [the wikipedia page for LDA – 36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_diisopropylamide)), does that refer to the pKA of the compound itself (LDA) or the protonated form?

Comment: That would be the pKa of the protonated form.